# Linux command to find all matching files from matching directories

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command

I want to list all matching files from matching directories. Could you please help.

e.g.

**Total Files:**

```
/target/a.txt
/target/module2/target/b.txt
/target/module2/target/OtherDir/NotRequired.txt
/target/module2/target/module3/target/c.txt
/target/module2/target/module3/target/anotherDir/NotRequired.txt
```

I need all the txt files in directories named "target". (only if parent is **target**)

**Expected Files:**

```
/target/a.txt
/target/module2/target/b.txt
/target/module2/target/module3/target/c.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Path helps you with the path details and you can put * to say that it can be anything.

find . -path */foldername/filename.extension